# ON method won't trigger at first click on the page already loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, this

This was just a conflict between triggers applied to the textarea where i get the text and the a.comment trigger

// Read above first

Why this ON method won't work at first click when page load? . Only since i clicked on whatever part of the page , on the second click , the click event work. any ideas? BTW i'm using firefox with firebug, if you know a method to get better information to this weird behaviour here in firebug panel . i'll thank you any help. 
i'm using jquery-1.7.2.min .

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a.comment').on("click", function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
       var comment_text = $("#comment").val();
   if(comment_text !="Escriba aqui su comentario")
       {
      $.post("../load.php?comment_text="+comment_text, function(response){
        //on response
      })
       }
    });

});
```

this is the html portion:

```
<textarea id="comment"></textarea> /*only one on the page*/
<a id="c_id-XXX" class="comment"> Comment</a>  /* XXX = diferent num*/
```

Comment: What does the HTML portion look like?

Comment: try alert('in') before the $.post, would it work!!

Comment: Can you use setTimeout like that?

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan I use only the alert instead of the $.post and it does the same.

Comment: sorry guys , and thank you, my problem was a conflict with other trigger (elastic)

Answer (score 1):

take a look [here](http://jsbin.com/ujuzih/1/)

I've edited your work and now it's fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a.comment').on("click", function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
      alert('in'); //testing if we are in
       var comment_text = $("#comment").val();
   if(comment_text !="Escriba aqui su comentario")
       {
//no need for extra brackets here as long as you are not passing args.
      $.post("../load.php?comment_text="+comment_text,  
 function(response){
        //on response
      }); // no use for settimeout()
       }
      alert('out'); // checking that we have done it :)
    });     

});
```

*Hope that I helped*

Comment: Thanks for the help, i assume my problem is a conflict with another function i have on my code.